# Struggling with a Sql Join Statement. Fetching values from DIfferent Tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have three mysql database tables namely; `scheduled_messages`, `subscribed_services`, and `subscription_services_msisdn`.

`subscribed_services` has columns username and password. The id of this table = Primary Key and a foreign key to the other two tables.

`scheduled_messages` table has columns message, scheduled_at and subscribed_services_id which is a foreign key of table subscribed_services.

`subscription_services_msisdn` table has phone_number and subscribed_services_id which is a foreign key of table subscribed_services.

I need a sql statement that can get **message** FROM scheduled_messages WHERE scheduled_at = CURDATE() and

**phone_number** FROM subscription_services_msisdn WHERE subscribed_services_id = "SELECT subscribed_services_id FROM  scheduled_messages WHERE scheduled_at = CURDATE()"

and finally

**username**, **password** FROM subscribed_services WHERE id = "SELECT subscribed_services_id FROM  scheduled_messages WHERE scheduled_at = CURDATE()"

I came up with this join statement but does not work. I get 0 results even when there are on the tables.

```
SELECT message, phone_number, username, password from scheduled_messages 
inner join 
subscribed_services on scheduled_messages.id = subscribed_services.id 
inner join 
subscription_services_msisdn on scheduled_messages.subscribed_services_id = 
subscription_services_msisdn.subscribed_services_id where scheduled_messages.scheduled_at = CURDATE();
```

**Sample data**

```
from subscribed_services;
+----+---------+-----------+--------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+
| id | keyword | shortcode | org_id | username     | password  | created_at          | 
+----+---------+-----------+--------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 | Lawyer  | 21348     | 4      | Lawyer101API | qweasd123 | 2017-07-04 11:34:06 | 



from scheduled_messages;
+----+---------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | message                   | subscribed_services_id | scheduled_at        | created_at          |       
+----+---------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |  He also saw a poor widow |                      1 | 2017-07-04 11:32:52 | 2017-07-03 18:09:25 |
+----+---------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+



from subscription_services_msisdn;
+----+--------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | phone_number | subscribed_services_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+--------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 224718488444 |                      1 | 2017-07-03 17:57:33 | 2017-07-03 17:57:33 |
|  2 | 224717746565 |                      1 | 2017-07-03 17:58:41 | 2017-07-03 17:58:41 |
|  3 | 224718036864 |                      1 | 2017-07-04 11:32:52 | 2017-07-04 11:32:52 |
```

How can I get username, password, phone_number and message for the message scheduled at  for the current date?

Anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would  help.

Comment: What datatype is `scheduled_messages.scheduled_at` defined as?

Comment: @Bridge scheduled_at is timestamp.

Comment: "does not work." is not a problem description. Do you get an error? If so, what's the error.

Comment: As per your description, your third join condition is wrong. It should be `inner join subscription_services_msisdn on 
 subscribed_services.id = subscription_services_msisdn.subscribed_services_id `

Comment: Hey @PrabhatG I have made an update.

Comment: @Syntax101 : your `subscribed_services.id is 2` whereas `subscription_services_msisdn.subscribed_services_id is 1`. Join as well as data is not proper, you see ?

Comment: @PrabhatG oops ... seen and corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see, you have got your join condition wrong based on the schema description provided. Can you try this and let me know if you get proper results ?

```
SELECT 
b.message, c.phone_number, a.username, a.password 
from 
subscribed_services a
inner join
scheduled_messages b on a.id = b.subscribed_services_id
inner join 
subscription_services_msisdn c on a.id = c.subscribed_services_id 
where DATE(b.scheduled_at) = CURDATE();
```

Comment: Thank you... I did tweak it slightly to fix my scenario. `SELECT b.message, c.phone_number, a.username, a.password from subscribed_services a 
inner join 
subscription_services_msisdn c on a.id = c.subscribed_services_id 
inner join 
scheduled_messages b on a.id = b.subscribed_services_id where DATE(b.scheduled_at) = CURDATE()`

Comment: @Syntax101 : great, although I don't see any tweak. Mark it as answer if it helped.